# Symfony 3.3.10: Object not found and 404 Not Found-Routing Issue

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I am new to symfony framework. I have successfully installed framework. I have setup database also. I can redirect to landing page also. but when i start to redirect simple index page it gives me 404 not found. I have followed as per documents.

I did not get what is wrong.

if i write http://localhost/symfony_demo/web/lucky/number URL then getting following error
[image]

It i write http://localhost/symfony_demo/lucky/number then getting this error.
[image]

Document don't give detailed information that how to use urls.

My controller is like below inside src/AppBundle/Controller.

```
    // src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php
    namespace AppBundle\Controller;

    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;


    class LuckyController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/lucky/number")
         */
        public function numberAction()
        {
            $number = mt_rand(0, 100);

            return new Response(
                '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
            );
        }
}
```

I get reference from [reference link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html). They did not give how to write route for this. Still i write route like below

```
lucky_list:
    path:     /lucky/number
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Lucky:number }
```

Is there any configuration to enable routing?
Any help please

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html doc link

Comment: I have checked it and i wrote route but it also not works. let me add route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this;

```
http://localhost/symfony_demo/web/app_dev.php/lucky/number
```

If you do not use command console `bin/console server:run`  use it for web server.

If you use nginx for web ser, you should nginx configuration for Symfony.

Comment: `bin/console server:run` gives me error `[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  There are no commands defined in the "server" namespace.  `

Comment: ımm. okay, try it, `php bin/console server:run`

Comment: One more thing sir. currently url uses app_dev.php . If i am using app.php then it gives me error

Comment: if you use `php bin/console server:run` you should not write /web/app.php or /web/app_dev.php to url